# Цикл в цикле

Tags: python

Есть два цикла:

```
for i in range(300,305):
   pass

for i2 in range(1,5):
  pass
```

В результате нужно получить:

test 300

test 300 test 1

test301

test 301 test 2

И что-то немного запутался в двух березах...

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(5):
    print 'test {0}'.format(300 + i)
    print 'test {0} test {1}'.format(300 + i, 1+i)
```

Comment: Спасибо, пока писал начал вспоминать конструктивы.